# No logging in confluence web application

Tags: java, log4j, confluence

I am trying to enable logging for the below class in Confluence:

https://bitbucket.org/mryall/confluence-siteminder-authenticator/src/142de32b6be86321c9791df5dfced607314ed17d/src/main/java/com/atlassian/confluence/authenticator/siteminder/SiteMinderAuthenticator.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default&_ga=2.161258619.735769127.1516003521-2111736425.1515526840

E.g. I know this line:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Principal getUser(final HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    log.info("Starting SiteMinder Authentication for: {}", request.getRequestURI());
    Principal loggedInUser = getUserFromSession(request);
    if (loggedInUser != null) {
        log.debug("{} is already logged in.", loggedInUser.getName());
        return loggedInUser;
    }
```

is executed but nothing is written to catalina.out. In log4j.properties I have:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, confluencelog, errorlog
log4j.appender.confluencelog=com.atlassian.confluence.loggin‌​g.ConfluenceHomeLogA‌​ppender
```

Any ideas why nothing is printed to catalina.out from the above class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Confluence manual](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/working-with-confluence-logs-108364721.html) says:

> In order to unify logging across different application servers, Confluence uses the atlassian-confluence.log as its primary log, not the application server log.
>
> Once the initial startup sequence is complete, all logging will be to <confluence-home>/logs/atlassian-confluence.log. For example: c:/confluence/data/logs/atlassian-confluence.log.

So look for your entries from that file, not catalina.out.

Comment: There is no such file in /opt/atlassian/confluence/logs/ only the catalina.out,manager.[DATE].log, localhost.[DATE]

Comment: @u123 so to which one is your `confluencelog` configured in log4j.properties?

Comment: Currently I have: log4j.appender.confluencelog=com.atlassian.confluence.loggin‌​g.ConfluenceHomeLogA‌​ppender, see updated post

Comment: @u123 what is your home location in /confluence/WEB-INF/classes/confluence-init.properties ? is it `/opt/atlassian/confluence/`? have you checked folder `/opt/atlassian/confluence/data/logs`?

Comment: @u123 also, have you tried restarting confluence, as per [this bug entry](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONFSERVER-32438)

Comment: Ah that was it, the atlassian-confluence.log is in: atlassian/application-data/confluence/logs

Answer (score 0):

Your rootLogger level is WARN. It doesn't print lower level logs like INFO, DEBUG

You can set it to DEBUG which covers INFO level.

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, confluencelog, errorlog
```

But it will print a lot including these two.

```
>log.info("Starting SiteMinder Authentication for: {}", request.getRequestURI());,

>log.debug("{} is already logged in.", loggedInUser.getName());
```

[The best solution](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/log4j/log4j-log-levels-example/) is to set package log level to DEBUG. You can add a line into your *log4j.properties*

```
log4j.logger.com.atlassian.confluence.authenticator.siteminder=DEBUG, confluencelog
```

Comment: Sorry it was set to DEBUG level. And it still does not give any output in catalina.out

Comment: In this case it seems to the your _confluencelog_ appender is not a **org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender**. Could you share full _log4j.properties_

Comment: Currently I have: log4j.appender.confluencelog=com.atlassian.confluence.logging.ConfluenceHomeLogAppender